# Get previous occurrence of a LocalTime

Tags: java, time

How to get the previous occurrence of a specified [local time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/time/LocalTime.html) as an [instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/time/Instant.html), for the system timezone ?

This basically means getting today at specified time or yesterday at specified time depending whether the specified time for today is before or after now.

Of course, I need to take into account timezone switch because of daylight saving. That is, the timezone offset can be different for today and yesterday.

This is what I've got now :

```
public Instant getPreviousOccurence(LocalTime scheduledTime) {
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    Instant todayAtSpecifiedTime = now.with(scheduledTime);
    return todayAtSpecifiedTime.isAfter(now) ? todayAtSpecifiedTime.minus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS) : todayAtSpecifiedTime;
}
```

But after checking the source of `Instant.minus()`, I noticed that it removes 84600 seconds for a day, which would be wrong in my case. Additionally, I'm not sure whether `Instant.with()` will use the system timezone or UTC.

### Edit 1

In case there are no occurrence of the specified time for today (because of a timezone shift), the instant of the timezone shift should be returned. In case there are two occurrences of the specified time for today, the latest in the past should be returned.

### Edit 2

After checking with Product Owner, it turns out that in case there are two occurrences of the specified time within a day, always returning the first (or always returning the second) is fine. We don't need both.

Comment: If your first instant represents the second occurrence of the `LocalTime` in a day, would you want `getPreviousOccurrence` to return the first occurrence on the same day, or the occurrence on the previous day? Which time zone are you interested in? (You haven't specified one at the moment. I would advise against implicitly using the system default time zone.)

Comment: The timezone is Europe/Paris. In case the first instant represents the second occurrence of `LocalTime` in a day, the first occurence of the same day should be returned.

Comment: Okay... and if the occurrence is skipped entirely, keep going to the previous day, or do something different? (Sorry - there are lots of corner cases to think about here!) Basically `ZonedDateTime` is going to be the key type here...

Comment: If the occurrence is skipped entirely, the best would be to return the instant of the shift between the previous and the new timezone offset. Thank-you for your interest in my question Jon! I'll have a look at ZonedDateTime tomorrow when I get back to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to Jon Skeet for pointing me to ZonedDateTime. Here is my solution using this type.

```
public Instant getPreviousOccurence(LocalTime scheduledTime) {
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    ZonedDateTime todayAtScheduledTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(now, EUROPE_PARIS).with(scheduledTime).withEarlierOffsetAtOverlap();
    if (todayAtScheduledTime.toInstant().isAfter(now)) {
        return todayAtScheduledTime.minusDays(1).withEarlierOffsetAtOverlap().toInstant();
    } else {
        return todayAtScheduledTime.toInstant();
    }
}
```